# Using a pre-built database and connecting it to Flask web application

Tags: mysql, database, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a database file in my C drive  - mysqlsampledatabase.sql
this database consists of information which I need to display on my website using Flask framework.

I have an offices page which simply expects to display all the office id and details by fetching the data from that source database file mysqlsampledatabase.sql file

How can this be done ? Please help me with this.

I have attached the whole code's GitHub Repo
Link to the Repo -> [Link to the Project](https://github.com/codemonk1307/Flask-Office-WebApp)

---

[image: my Flask application structure is like this]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to install a database server, MariaDB for example [MariaDB Documentation](https://mariadb.org/documentation/), and create the database using your sql file, using [command line](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mysql-command-line-client/) or some program like phpMyAdmin.

Then you can use Pymysql to connect with the database what did you create. You can find how install and use on [Pymysql Documentation](https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)